# Using windows task scheduler how can i execute my exe file after IIS RESET

Tags: iis, scheduled-tasks

I have a scenario where i need to execute .exe after IIS reset. In windows task scheduler we can get option to run execitable file for some condition where we can select IIS configuration/ log and can provide event id to match.
I search couple of option but did not find any.
Can anybody suggest - how can i run my executable file after IIS reset happens using task scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735265(v=ws.10).aspx),

3201 is start

3202 is stop

> 3201 IIS start command received from user %1. The logged data is the status code.
>
> 3202 IIS stop command received from user %1. The logged data is the status code.

Since, IISReset is a stop and start operation, you can have the trigger based on the start event, i.e., 3202.

Your task trigger will be like this:

[image]

You can cross-check the event viewer for the events from IISReset

[image]